# I get an error message in the command line when I try to access Mysql in the command line

Tags: mysql, terminal

I have installed Mysql from the Mysql Community on my late 2019 Mac.  I used the below sudo code and then I typed in my my Mac computer password.  The Terminal says file exists.  I really don't know what that means or what to do.  Then I typed in the root password that I set up during the installation of Mysql.  The Terminal says commend not found: mysql

Can someone please take a look at the below?

```
davidd.christie@Davids-Macbook-Pro ~ % sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin

Password:

in:/usr/local/bin: File exists

davidd.christie@davids-MacBook-Pro ~ % mysql -u root -p

zsh:command not found:mysql

davidd.christie@davids-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try reboot your Mac? I think that you need to reload shell.

Comment: Hi Pedro,  how do I reboot it to reload the shell?

Comment: You can try with exec $SHELL